# Fan constantly on, Dell Inspiron 15R, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, dell, fan, fancontrol

**Problem**

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15R. As soon as I boot, the fan starts at full speed and stays constantly on.
I've seen similar posts, where installing fan control apps are recommended like

```
i8kmon  
jupiter
mesa-utils
```

but in general, these do not allow for automatic fan speed control and one has to manually set the fan speed, while keeping track of the processor's temperature. See: [Similar post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251705/dell-7520-inspiron-15r-se-fan-on-full-speed-on-12-04-12-10-13-04)

**Technical specs**

```
 - Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4
 - RAM: 6 GB
 - Disk: 500 GB
 - Graphics: Standard Intel drivers
 - OS type: Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit)
```

**lm-sensors**

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +40.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +45.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Any hint on how to solve this ?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated video card besides that Intel thingy?

Comment: I just realized that without the dual monitor display, the problem does not appear ... If I start Ubuntu without plugging in the external monitor (Dell 23"), the fan does not start running at full speed.
The problem may rely in the Intel drivers ??

Comment: @OrangeTux: No, the only Graphics card is the Intel one, so no external or Ubuntu drivers.

Comment: @Nicolas what happens if you suspend? My Asus laptop sometimes does the same, and if I suspend and wakeup the fan stops.

Comment: @Salem thanks for the suggestion, but as soon as I start it back, the fan starts running again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same notebook as yours, and the solution for me was 'i8kutils'. In this package the script 'i8kmon' is for automatic control.

Some tips are:

- Put `ENABLED=1` in `/etc/default/i8kmon`
- Put `set config(auto)        1` in `/etc/i8kmon.conf`

I hope it helps.

Comment: It seems to be working ! I'll keep an eye on the temperatures and let you know if anything changes.

Comment: `i8kmon` did stop the fan noise, but somehow the _automatic_ adjustment of fan speed does not work. Even if the temperatures are higher than the thresholds defined in `/etc/i8kmon`, the fan does not start. Any suggestions ?

Comment: With the log we can have a better understand. To do that, just issue '$ sudo service i8kmon stop', and execute the script '/usr/bin/i8kmon' manually with the parameter '--verbose'. I think 20 seconds of log is sufficient.

Comment: Found the problem. I was not setting the temperature thresholds in the proper script. Thanks again !