# Dell fans not working

Tags: 14.04, dell, fan

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my DELL Inspiron 15R.

Since I have installed it, my fan is constantly spinning, even I do absolutely nothing.
I found [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842775) and I decided to install i8kutils. Just after I installed it, my fans are now **not spinning at all**!! This is very dangerous for my laptop... If I run i8kfan -1 2 my fan is spinning for 1-2 seconds in full power, and then stops again. What I should do?

I also tried the following that exist in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329448/fan-constantly-on-dell-inspiron-15r-ubuntu-12-04#382533):

Put `ENABLED=1` in `/etc/default/i8kmon`

Put set `config(auto)        1` in `/etc/i8kmon.conf`

**UPDATE:**

Please also find the output of this command $ /usr/bin/i8kmon --verbose [here](http://pastebin.com/6w4Abv5U)

ps1: I should mention that my laptops fans work *flawlesly* when using windows.

ps2: I also know that there are numerous similar questions out there. I spent many hours studying them and I couldn't find any good answer. *Therefore, I am seeking for a good answer, than closing down my question as duplicate.*

Comment: As I still have the problem @Oli, can you please unblock the question? The question you proposed that is similar to mine does not resolve my problem

Comment: If this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/522954/setting-temperature-thresholds-in-i8kmon-ubuntu-14-04/527333#527333

Comment: This helped me (specifically, the `smm` command described in the link): http://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found it (I think :p). The site mentioned in the question says that the configuration should be copied at the file: `/etc/i8mon`.

However, they should be written here: `~/.i8kmon` instead. And I think it works fine this way.

---

#### Editor's Note

The actual error was in the [forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842775) which OP was following. Although the author intended to say to change in `/etc/i8kmon` file, They mistakenly wrote `/etc/i8mon` instead in the code section. Since, OP was following the code, the configurations didn't work.

OP saved the configs in `~/.i8kmon` and that worked because user's config stored in `~/` is preferred than the ones in `/etc` and that way it was overriding the default configs. So, OP's assumption is wrong. Both `/etc/i8kmon` and `~/.i8kmon` would work. The error was in somewhere else.