# my laptop is heated and battery drained fast

Tags: 13.04, ati, laptop, overheating

when I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop, it is hot and battery drains fast , I have to plug-in power supply while I'm working on it.

Using Windows 8 on my laptop, doesn't cause the same symptoms.

I have a Dell Inspiron  n5520 15R

Graphics: AMD 1gb Radeon HD 7676m

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you installed tlp and bumblebee?

Comment: No @Crake , i haven't installed it

Answer (score 1):

What Crake said makes a lot of sense. Are you guys sure you weren't running the Intel iGPU under Windows while you're now running that mobile Radeon? Bumblebee would alleviate that, AFAIK.

Comment: And here you go: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Eh. Never mind. My brain experienced a segfault, it seems. Bumblebee is for NVIDIA Optimus. Obviously wouldn't help with his Radeon. Thanks for the link.

Comment: bumblebee doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problems with a inspiron 7520. And often there aren't many good or any options at all to fix them. All I found that could help you stands here: [dell 7520 (inspiron 15R SE), fan on full speed on 12.04, 12.10, 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251705/dell-7520-inspiron-15r-se-fan-on-full-speed-on-12-04-12-10-13-04) Just do it for you're Hardware.

Note: If you're fan also turns to full speed check out 13.10 they fixed a bit in the kernel.